# Is there some way to intercept and modify the html output stream in asp.net, to combine the javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html, css

Is there some way to intercept the HTML output stream in asp.net and make modifications? Eg using httpmodules or something? I know this is possible using java servlets and assume there must be an elegant way to do this with asp.net.

My purpose is to combine the many javascript files into one composite script which has been minified/packed, to make the page load faster.

Eg, if my page normally outputs the following in the page head:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/blah.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/yada.js"></script>
```

I want to replace that with the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/all.js"></script>
```

(also i realise i'll have to create all.js somehow).
Thanks!

Comment: Also want to do the same with multiple css files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set [`Response.Filter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.filter.aspx).

Comment: Yeah - something like that sounds great. With this, will it only ever allow one filter?

Comment: @Chris: No; filters can be chained.  The `Filter` getter handles this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an interesting article. I haven't tried this, just did a search.

I know that Telerik does something similar for their controls.

http://geekswithblogs.net/rashid/archive/2007/07/25/Combine-Multiple-JavaScript-and-CSS-Files-and-Remove-Overheads.aspx