# Insert JavaScript to Head Tag After Page is Almost Finished

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there a way using a web form in ASP.NET to insert a script reference to the head tag once the page has almost finished `Page_Load`?

For example:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <!-- generate script about content here --->
</head>
<body>
    <!-- generate content here --->
</body>
</html>
<% 
    //Write script about content, insert to head tag.
%>
```

Comment: Not easily... You can try to rewrite HTML with something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599987/is-there-some-way-to-intercept-and-modify-the-html-output-stream-in-asp-net-to ... Changing your code to put scripts in place you want them to be will likely be better solution.

Comment: Thanks. I had an idea earlier and I am going to try it out this weekend. There doesn't seem to be anything built in that let's me do this, so I will have to get plenty creative to make it work.

Comment: You have two different frameworks listed: `ASP.NET MVC`, where it is done one way, and `web form` in your question text, which refers to ASP.NET Webforms. Which one do you want it done for?

Comment: I listed MVC because the design pattern needs to work for that as well. I used a web form as an example for readability.

Comment: To clarify, my posted solution, albeit departing from the MVC Framework, does the job (I suppose I could unnecessarily "chop things up" just for adhering to the idea that complicated + convoluted + intricate = better), but that's not how I operate.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a way to do this that works with both web forms and MVC.

Serialize an instance of a class using Newtonsoft and then store the JSON in the memory cache. Then, when a new instance of the class is created, pull the JSON out of the cache and initialize the instance with it. Last, I created a web form that pulls out the cached copy to generate JavaScript that is then referenced in the head tag.

Comment: I was down voted on this solution for some reason, but my experience after implementing has been good. Any input as to why this is not this best solution is much appreciated. Thanks in advance -Josh